# Updating a MySQL table with the COUNT of another

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm trying to update a column in table `Profiles` with a COUNT from another table `Videos`.  All videos are stored in the `Videos` table, and I want to create a column in `Profiles` called `VideoCount` which shows the COUNT of that user's videos in the `Videos` table.

Basically, I want to run a cron job - so I need to know how to find the COUNT of a user's videos in the `Videos` table and then UPDATE that user's `VideoCount` in `Profiles` with this count number.

To identify who's uploaded which video, `Videos`.`Owner` and `Profiles`.`ID` should be made to match.  Does anybody know the SQL which I need to run for the PHP file cron job?

Comment: That's the kind of thing you do with a trigger : when you insert a row in your Videos table, you increment the column in your Profiles table.

Comment: @Vincent Savard if there are frequent uploads its ok to use a cron (there is no need for 100% correct Count-Columns (imo)) and since he wants to add this column he needs this sql-statement anyway

Comment: @maggie : It's his call. But with a trigger, he wouldn't need this sql statement, he'd only do a `UPDATE table SET col = col + 1 -- etc`.

Comment: @Vincent Savard its a diference between 1000 UPDATEs per sec and 1 in 5 Minutes.

Comment: @maggie : it's a difference between being accurate or wrong. Plus, you most likely have no idea how many queries Jamie has to do. With your query, you may update 95% of the table for no reason. As I said, it's his call, he knows more than us about the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Profiles
SET VideoCount = (
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Videos
   WHERE Videos.Owner = Profiles.ID);
```

as simple as it can be^^

and if you want it fancy: all the triggers you might need:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER increaseVideoCount AFTER INSERT ON Videos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Profiles SET VideoCount = VideoCount + 1 WHERE ID = NEW.Owner;
  END;
//

CREATE TRIGGER decreaseVideoCount AFTER DELETE ON Videos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Profiles SET VideoCount = VideoCount - 1 WHERE ID = OLD.Owner;
  END;
//

CREATE TRIGGER checkVideoCount AFTER UPDATE ON Videos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.Owner <> NEW.Owner THEN
      UPDATE Profiles SET VideoCount = VideoCount + 1 WHERE ID = NEW.Owner;
      UPDATE Profiles SET VideoCount = VideoCount - 1 WHERE ID = OLD.Owner;
    END IF;
  END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: +1 and linked to @Rahul Mehta's answer, that would be complete.

Comment: Thanks. My hosting company (for some weird reason) disallows MySQL triggers - so I either had to use a cron job, or update the PHP so it updates when a file is uploaded (which is the option I plumped for).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update video count that you can upadate video count at the time of upload, so as i think there is no need for the cron job for this.

```
update profiles set videocount=(select count(*) from videos where profileid =$profileid ) 
where profileid=$profileid
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
UPDATE A SET VideoCount = 
(
  SELECT COUNT(B.*) 
  FROM Videos AS B INNER JOIN Profiles AS B ON (A.Profile_ID = B.Owner_ID)  
  GROUP BY B.Owner_ID
);
```

I'm not sure this syntax is completely correct. give it a try